# How to get system (Windows) memory in R?

Tags: r, windows, memory-management, ram

Does anyone know how to get the memory (RAM) used by the system from R?

I'm using windows. `memory.size()` and `mem_used()` functions give you the memory used by R and R objects respectively, but they doesn't consider the memory already occupied by the system and other software.

Comment: Have you tried the Windows Task-Manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way using `shell` on Windows:

```
shell('systeminfo | findstr Memory')
#Total Physical Memory:     16,271 MB
#Available Physical Memory: 8,011 MB
#Virtual Memory: Max Size:  32,655 MB
#Virtual Memory: Available: 24,040 MB
#Virtual Memory: In Use:    8,615 MB
```

You could use a different string instead of Memory if you want more granular results.

Comment: However, I can´t save it in a R object. E.g., m=shell('systeminfo | findstr Memory') doesn't work. Do you know how I can save the 'Available Physical Memory' as a character or a numeric object?

Comment: `shell('systeminfo | findstr Memory', intern = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks again! It is perfect.